How to store and retrieve user credentials from AWS secrets manager to selenium java bdd scripts?
How to store and retrieve user credentials from AWS secrets manager to selenium java bdd scripts
mine is a selenium java bdd cucumber maven project .
Is it even possible it retrieve the user credentials from AWS secrets manager?
